# Error while installing Pillow on CentOS 6.6

Tags: python, postgresql, centos, python-imaging-library

I am trying to install `psycopg2` as well as `Pillow 3.0` for Cent OS 6.6 from last 2 days. But it was not installing and throwing the errors.

I looked up into all answers from Stack Overflow as well as blogs, but nothing works for me.

Stack trace while installing Pillow is **(NOTE: I also tried each solution available on the Stack Overflow for this too)**:

```
(first)[root@localhost ~]# pip install Pillow
Downloading/unpacking Pillow
  Downloading Pillow-3.0.0.tar.gz (9.6MB): 9.6MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package Pillow
    Single threaded build, not installing mp_compile:1 processes

Installing collected packages: Pillow
  Running setup.py install for Pillow
    Single threaded build, not installing mp_compile:1 processes

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/root/.virtualenvs/first/build/Pillow/setup.py", line 767, in <module>
        zip_safe=not debug_build(),
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/root/.virtualenvs/first/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 56, in run
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 563, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 127, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 337, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/root/.virtualenvs/first/build/Pillow/setup.py", line 515, in build_extensions
        % (f, f))
    ValueError: --enable-jpeg requested but jpeg not found, aborting.
    Complete output from command /root/.virtualenvs/first/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/root/.virtualenvs/first/build/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-MaTP1u-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /root/.virtualenvs/first/include/site/python2.7:
    Single threaded build, not installing mp_compile:1 processes

running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/OleFileIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

running egg_info

writing Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



reading manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'

writing manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

copying PIL/OleFileIO-README.md -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

running build_ext

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/root/.virtualenvs/first/build/Pillow/setup.py", line 767, in <module>

    zip_safe=not debug_build(),

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "/root/.virtualenvs/first/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 56, in run

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 563, in run

    self.run_command('build')

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 127, in run

    self.run_command(cmd_name)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 337, in run

    self.build_extensions()

  File "/root/.virtualenvs/first/build/Pillow/setup.py", line 515, in build_extensions

    % (f, f))

ValueError: --enable-jpeg requested but jpeg not found, aborting.

----------------------------------------
Command /root/.virtualenvs/first/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/root/.virtualenvs/first/build/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-MaTP1u-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /root/.virtualenvs/first/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /root/.virtualenvs/first/build/Pillow
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

NOTE: I have installed all packages `postgresql-devel` , `setuptools` and `python-devel`. The root is using `Python 2.6.6` and `virtualenv` is using `Python 2.7.10`.

Please help me with this.

Comment: The error you have is explicit that it can't find the `pg_config` executable. So check that you can see `pg_config` and which it to see where it's installed.

Comment: Its inside `/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config`. I added in the PATH in my `bashrc` file.
`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config` 
But it throws same error.

Comment: As the message says, "add the **directory containing** pg_config", i.e. `/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/`. As for the second error, it appears to be the first Google result for "ValueError: --enable-jpeg".

Comment: `psycopg2` installed but `Pillow` is not installing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error (since deleted) is explicit that it can't find the `pg_config` executable. Add the path `/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin` to `PATH`.

The second error, installing Pillow, is failing because you haven't installed `libjpeg-devel` and `zlib-devel`. Install those and you should be grand.

---

For further information:

Pillow 3.0 changed things in how `zlib` and `libjpeg` are handled. This was reported in [python-pillow/Pillow issue#1457](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1457).

Comment: BTW @RajatGupta the first time you accept an answer it adds 25 rep. When you remove the acceptance it takes that 25 rep away. When you accepted this answer again the rep hasn't been added back. Just FYI, people can get annoyed.